# how to split by letter-followed-by-period?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to split text by the letter-followed-by-period rule. So I do this:

```
$text = 'One two. Three test. And yet another one';
$splitted_text = preg_split("/\w\./", $text);
print_r($splitted_text);
```

Then I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => One tw [1] => Three tes [2] => And yet another one )
```

But I do need it to be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => One two [1] => Three test [2] => And yet another one )
```

How to settle the matter?

Answer (score 2):

use [`explode`](http://it.php.net/explode) statement

```
$text = 'One two. Three test. And yet another one';
$splitted_text = explode(".", $text);
print_r($splitted_text);
```

Update

```
$splitted_text = explode(". ", $text);
```

using ". " the `explode` statement check also the space.

You can use any kind of delimiters also a phrase non only a single char

Comment: might want to make the delimiter ". " in this case to get rid of the space, but yeah.  this.

Answer (score 2):

Its splitting on the letter and the period.  If you want to test to make sure that there is a letter preceding the period, you need to use a positive look behind assertion.

```
$text = 'One two. Three test. And yet another one';
$splitted_text = preg_split("/(?<=\w)\./", $text);
print_r($splitted_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex is an overkill here, you can use `explode` easily. Since a explode based answer is already give, I'll give a regex based answer:

```
$splitted_text = preg_split("/\.\s*/", $text);
```

Regex used: `\.\s*`

- `\.` - A dot is a meta char. To match a literal match we escape it.
- `\s*` - zero or more white space.

If you use the regex: `\.`

You'll have some leading spaces in some of the pieces created.